# $\sqrt{n}$ in scaled random walk

Tags: random-walk

In a reference, it is stated that

$W^{(n)}(t)=\frac
{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_{nt}$

with :

$W^{(n)}(t)$ as scaled random walk and

$M_{nt}=\sum_{j=1}^{nt}X_j$.

Where does $\sqrt{n}$ come from? Would you please explain with its relationship with $\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}$?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not entirely sure about your notation here, if the $X_j$ are iid then your $W^n$ have constant variance. This is in turn because of the basic properties

$$\text{Var} \left ( \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \right ) = n \text{Var}(X_1) \\
\text{Var}(cX)=|c|^2 \text{Var}(X)$$

when the $X_j$ are iid and $c$ is a constant. Combining these gives

$$\text{Var} \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \right ) = \frac{1}{n} n \text{Var}(X_1)=\text{Var}(X_1).$$

This is probably why you would want the walk to be scaled in that way. This same scaling is used in, for example, the central limit theorem.